# Laravel message: "Illegal string offset 'user_id'"

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-4

```
      $validator = Validator::make(
            Input::all(),
            [
                'new_password' => [
                    'required',
                    'password_reused',
                    'min:8',
                    'regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/'
                ],
                'confirm_new_password' => 'required|same:new_password',
                'old_password'         => 'required|hashmatch:password',
            ],
            [
                'confirm.different' => Lang::get('account.password.errors.wrong_new_password'),
                'regex'             => Lang::get('account.password.errors.wrong_complexity'),
                'confirm.same'      => Lang::get('account.password.errors.wrong_confirm_password'),
                'hashmatch'         => Lang::get('account.password.errors.wrong_old_password')
            ]
        );
```

```
$validator->fails()
```

After `fails` function, I am getting  `"Illegal string offset 'user_id'"` and I am not sure why this is happening.

This is Laravel 4.2, I know this is old but we can't update.

Comment: _we can't update_ is an attitude that really needs to change.

Comment: You have to share more details

Comment: what kind of info do you need more?

Comment: I can see I can get the params from request as well using `Input:all()`

Comment: What is the full error you are seeing? Which file and line number?

Comment: This is the full error.
`"Illegal string offset 'user_id'"`
I am getting this in the client side with 500 error